# Unable to Align data in Datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

Hi I have issue with alignment of data in the spark datagrid column after Rendering. All the headers are aligned towards left, however i would like to do the following
1. Middle the column header name.
2. Align the text to right.
3.Freeze the first column so that when i do horizontal scroll, the first column should not move horizontally.

Any help in this regard would be highly grateful.

Thanks and regards

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                    clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flashx.textLayout.formats.BackgroundColor;

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.states.SetStyle;

            private const POSITIVE_COLOR:uint = 0x000000; // Black
            private const NEGATIVE_COLOR:uint = 0xFF0000; // Red

            override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {

                if (this.data) {
                    if (column.labelFunction != null ) {
                        lblData.text = column.labelFunction( data, column );

                        setStyle("color", (parseInt(this.data.st1) < 0) ? NEGATIVE_COLOR : POSITIVE_COLOR);

                    } else {
                        lblData.text = data[column.dataField];
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Label id="lblData" top="9" left="7" textAlign="right"/>

</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 2):

> 2/ Align the text to right.

I'll start with the easiest one.
In your custom item renderer, you're still aligning to the left (`left="7"`). You have two options to fix this:

```
<s:Label id="lblData" top="9" right="7"/>
```

will align the Label to the right and cause text overflow to the left

```
<s:Label id="lblData" top="9" left="7" right="7" textAlign="right"/>
```

will make the Label take all the available space, align the text to the right and truncate the text if it's too big

> 1/ Middle the column header name.

I think the only way is to create a custom headerRenderer.

- copy the entire DefaultGridHeaderRenderer
- find the Label with id "labelDisplay"
- change its `textAlign` property to `center`
- assign the custom headerRenderer:
  `<s:GridColumn headerRenderer="path.to.CenteredHeaderRenderer"/>`

> 3/ Freeze the first column so that when i do horizontal scroll, the first column should not move horizontally.

I'm afraid this is going to require some serious hacking. If you don't want to dive in and create a customized DataGrid, I think your best bet is to fake it:

- create a List to represent the fixed column
- create a DataGrid to represent the other columns
- turn off the List's vertical scrollbar: you wanna controll the scrolling through the grid
- bind their vertical scrolling position: when the DataGrid is vertically scrolled, the List must follow and vice-versa
- bind their selected items
- do some skinning to make it look like one DataGrid

Comment: My one thing to add is that the original MX DataGrid does have a lockedColumnCount property that can be used for freezing a column: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridBase.html#lockedColumnCount .If this is important, switching back to the MX component may be easier than trying to do workarounds.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Thanks. Didn't know about that one. Haven't done much work in Flex 3. Seems there are _some_ things there I've been missing out on.

Comment: there is a lockedRowCount too if you want to lock rows.  Both are about as "bullet proof" as the MX DataGrid, for whatever that is worth.

Comment: As for freezing first column in spark datagrid, you can also dive deep inside grid's layout and do some complex modifications, like override some functionality in `GridLayour` for grid itself and `LayoutBase` for headers. Or you can do as RIAstar said by making double two grids or list + grid and do some skinning, but by doing this I am pretty sure there can be some data synchronization and visual problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot RIAstar. When i use the DefaultGridHeaderRenderer the header seems to wrap/expand as i scroll horizontally.Any fix for this?

Comment: I don't understand what `wrap/expand` means. Note that DataGrid _always_ uses DefaultGridHeaderRenderer by default.